# VSS Analyze - Access to file [filename] is denied

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Our VSS database appears to be horribly out of shape.  I've been trying to archive and run "analyze" and keep getting "Access to file [filename] is denied.  The file may be read-only, may be in use, or you may not have permission to write to the file.  Correct this problem and run analyze again."  No one is logged into SourceSafe (including myself) and I'm running the analyze utility from the VS command prompt as follows:

`analyze -v -f -bbackuppath databasepath`

I get similar errors if I try and create project archives from the `ssadmin` tool.

The database is on a network share, and we're running VSS 2005 v8.0.50727.42.  I'd love to be able to do this, as it would be a first step in a move away from VSS.

Thanks in advance.

*More Info*
Every time I run analyze, the file that spawns the access denied message changes.  It's almost as if running analyze unlocks that file so that the next time I get through to the next one.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your question and I apologize if this is annoying: If you have the chance, get rid of VSS. It's widely regarded as the most incompetent of source control tools. Database corruption and loss of files is common, and it's no fun to work with either. There are much better programs available for $FREE . If your code is important enough for source control, it's too important to trust to VSS.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz - Yes, I know, that's part of why I'm trying to get things in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with our VSS database as well when we tried to most recently analyze and repair.

We did a few things to get it working.

1. Turned off the network share, apparently we still had users accessing the share that we couldn't see, this helped most of the time.
2. Otherwise we copied the repository locally, then ran analyze on it from there.

Neither solution is ideal, but we were in a critical situation and it was the only way we got it to work.

Comment: After you copied it locally and ran analyze, did you then remove the original on the network share and copy the "fixed" version back up?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what we did.